# React JS, Why my page tile is not changing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change my page title but its not changing, so what's the problem here I can't find it xD.
first i imported my cards.js and created here cards all is working, not working only part of changing the title.

```
  import React from 'react';
  import Cards from './Components/Cards/Cards'

  class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
      cards: [
        { name: 'Jack', photo: 'cool photo' },
        { name: 'Gorge', photo: 'norm photo' },
      ],
      pageTitle: 'Cards'
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Cards
            name={this.state.cards[0].name}
            photo={this.state.cards[0].photo}
          />
          <Cards
            name={this.state.cards[1].name}
            photo={this.state.cards[1].photo}
          />
        </div >
      )
    }
  }

  export default App
```

Comment: what you mean by pagetitle ? you want to change app title `React App` ?

Comment: Which part of the above code so you expect to change the title?

Comment: YES I want to change it

Comment: pageTitle: 'Cards' this part inside state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the below to your component:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { pageTitle } = this.state;
  document.title = pageTitle;
}
```

Alternatively I think you can use packages like React Helmet: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet